# Checkbox Subscribe for MailChimp with React JS web application

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp, subscribe

I'm trying to integrate a MailChimp checkbox opt-in feature on an existing React form. The entire site is a React web application. I've been checking around for solutions for hours, but still can't find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mailchimp 3.0 API

1. Create an API key here: https://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
2. Send a POST request to the following endpoint with your user data

Endpoint:
`https://<data_center>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/`

Structure of data to send:

`{
    "email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": "Urist",
        "LNAME": "McVankab"
    }
}`

You can get the `data_center` for your Mailchimp account when you enter to your dashboard, in the web browser check the URL. If for example, you have `https://us7.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/` your `data_center` will be `us7`.

And to obtain the `list_id` of the list you want your users to subscribe, check the following link as there are several ways to obtain it: [Find your list ID](https://mailchimp.com/eN/help/find-your-list-id/?utm_source=mc-api&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=apidocs)

After that you just have to handle the data for your subscriber into React state and send it on your form submit.

For more details, check Mailchimp API 3.0 documentation [here](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/)